# Why are the definitions of "fottere" so biased towards the man?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, verbs

I came here to ask this question based on [a question in the Spanish language](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23922/12637) stack based on the origin of the Spanish word *joder* (somewhat equivalent to *fottere*, though *follar* would be closer). In my answer there I learnt the Italian word *fottere* is quite an old one, but the surprise came when I looked up its meaning.

You see, in Spanish [the official defintion of *joder*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MVjNCIs) is as follows:

> Poseer sexualmente a alguien.

I found [the equivalent definition here](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/F/fottere.shtml) for *fottere* in Italian:

> Possedere qlcu. sessualmente.

But I found that definition only in one dictionary online. In [other](http://www.grandidizionari.it/Dizionario_Italiano/parola/F/fottere.aspx?query=fottere) [three](https://www.dizionario-italiano.it/dizionario-italiano.php?parola=fottere) [dictionaries](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/F/fottere.php) the definition was:

> Possedere sessualmente una donna.

So my question is why are the definitions of Italian *fottere* so biased towards the man possessing a woman? What happens when the woman takes the initiative, or even when two women make the sexual act? Can't a woman *fottere* a man or another woman? Is the word used in those cases or do you use another one?

Comment: I don't know what that anonymous “dizionario italiano” is, but all of the main Italian dictionaries ([Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fottere), Zingarelli, Devoto-Oli, [De Mauro](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/fottere)) give only variations on “possedere sessualmente” and, intransitively, “avere rapporti sessuali”, without ever mentioning males nor females. On the other hand, *possedere* has in itself the connotation of being, so to say, the active part in the sexual act.

Comment: @DaG it's funny then how I used the first four results from Google when I searched for "dizionario italiano" and those dictionaries ended up not being reliable at all. :-D

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: Some important dictionaries (Zingarelli, Devoto-Oli) are behind a paywall, so Google won't return them. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word ***fottere*** can be used for a man and also for a woman, grammatically gender doesn't matter.

Obviously the bias you noticed comes from history and tradition, when in the past (and somewhere also now usually) the man is considered stronger and the part that takes the initiative.

Please consider that the word ***[fottere](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fottere/)*** has other meanings in Italian:

> **fóttere** v. tr. [lat. *fŭttĕre, class. fŭtuĕre] (io fótto, ecc.), volg.
>   – Possedere sessualmente; avere rapporti sessuali con qualcuno:
>   Dormirem tutti due senza pensieri; Perché ’l fotter a tutti sempre
>   piace (Berni). Fig., **ingannare (to trick),**  **imbrogliare (to cheat) o anche sopraffare (to defeat),
>   ridurre all’impotenza (to reduce to impotence**, e sim. (cfr. l’analogo uso di fregare,
>   buggerare e sim.): *m’ha fottuto, quel cialtrone!; voleva farmi lo
>   sgambetto, ma io l’ho fottuto* (opp.: *ma è restato fottuto lui*); anche
>   bocciare, vincere: *all’esame lo hanno fottuto; il candidato è stato
>   fottuto dai suoi nemici nel partito.* Locuzioni: *mandare qualcuno a
>   farsi f., andare a farsi f.*, mandare, andare a quel paese; fottersene
>   di qualcuno, di qualche cosa, infischiarsene, fregarsene. ◆ Part.
>   pass. fottuto, anche come agg., senza un preciso sign. proprio ma
>   usato come epiteto ingiurioso o come espressione di sfogo: *sei un
>   porco fottuto; avere una sfortuna fottuta; che caldo fottuto!; quel
>   baron fottuto* (v. barone2); *non ce l’ho fatta, mondo fottuto!*

Comment: In Catalan we have also the verb ["fotre"](https://dlc.iec.cat/results.asp?txtEntrada=fotre&operEntrada=0) which may also have this meaning. But, in colloquial speech, it can also mean "to do" and many other things, so we use it a lot (but only in informal situations).

Comment: I don't agree completely: saying that “Maria fotte Antonio” seems to suggest more the other meanings of *fottere* (swindling him etc.), rather than just having sex with him.

Comment: @DaG: But maybe the interpretation would change if one says "Maria fotte con Antonio"?

Comment: Indeed, @Charo. Perhaps it's not the most natural way of saying it (*Maria scopa con Antonio* would sound more natural), but it also depends on one's idiolect.

Comment: For what is worth, for me *fottere* is a very uncommon word when used in the literal meaning (both for men and women), in my idiolect *scopare* is way more natural to use.

Comment: I'm from Tuscany and to my ear "Maria fotte Antonio" also suggests something else, as @DaG observed.

Answer (score 5):

*Fottere* comes from the Latin [*futuere*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/futuo), and it means *penetrate vaginally*.

So, originally, this could *literally* only be done by a man to a woman.

> "According to the classicist Holt N. Parker (1997), sexual
>   categorization in ancient Rome was based on a fundamental distinction
>   between sexual activity and passivity, with no special attention being
>   paid to the homo/hetero distinction that is fundamental for modern
>   Westerners. 'Active' sexuality in the Roman system meant using the
>   penis to penetrate one of three bodily orifices.

[Cameron, *Language and Sexuality*]

Nowadays I believe you would use, from less to more crude, *fare (al)l'amore con*, *fare sesso con* or *scopare (con)* - or any of dozens of synonyms - that are more or less gender neutral.

> What happens when the woman takes the initiative

I've heard distinctions made as to the initiating party by using the transitive or intransitive form of *scopare*, or even *farsi scopare*.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this Online Italian Etymological Dictionary](http://www.etimo.it/), the proper meaning of the word “fottere” is “to plant” (a seed, etc.); from this, the meaning of “having sexual intercourse” would have developed, but with an easily understandable connection with the idea of penetration.  As a matter of fact, “*fottere*” (*qualcuna/o*) does not mean “to have sexual intercourse” (with somebody) in its broadest and most general sense, but, more specifically, “to penetrate” (somebody).  This explains why, in cultures or in times still dominated by sexual stereotypes, the verb could be defined as “*possedere sessualmente una donna*”.  Of course, it may be the case that “*A fotta B*” (in the sexual sense, cf. @abarisone’s answer for the meaning of *fottere* related to cheating) for all the four possible combinations of A’s and B’s genders, although it is likely, in the case of A being a female, that the use of some kind of device is implicitly understood.

Comment: That etymological dictionary is quite dated and not always reliable. I am not saying that this particular etymology (i.e., the original meaning being “to plant”) is wrong, but I'd like to see an independent conformation, precisely because it's very interesting.

Comment: Neither [this](https://books.google.it/books?id=728Q-hLxaD0C&pg=PT547&lpg=PT547&dq=%22futuere%22&source=bl&ots=YB8ii55R1v&sig=VEOtRLS07bwptoXrEDkBs-AaUpE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjlhNnBxPjYAhVCtBQKHZ5wCU04ChDoAQhYMAs#v=onepage&q=%22futuere%22&f=false), nor [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_profanity#Futuere:_intercourse) (of dubious reliability that they are too) seem to confirm.

Comment: @DaG: Well, actually the Wikipedia source mentions the root “fu-” as a possible etymology.  I agree, anyway, that the matter both deserves and requires further investigation.